# IF statement in .cls file. How to control it from .tex file?

Tags: documentclass-writing, ifthenelse

Minimum working code is attached herewith. If I change 1 to 0 in \newcommand{\numsections}{1}, I get heading without number, and to get numbered heading, I have to go to .cls file. I don't want the user to go inside the .cls file to change whether section numbering should be used or not! Please check.

```
\documentclass[ieee]{file}

\begin{document}
\section{first section}
\end{document}
```

and the .cls file

```
\ProvidesClass{file}
\LoadClass[12pt,a4paper]{report}

\newcommand{\numsections}{1}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\if\numsections1
\titleformat{\section}{}{\thesection.\ }{}{}
\else
\titleformat{\section}{}{}{}{}
\fi
```

Comment: note `\if\numsections1`  should probably be `\ifnum` or better `\newif` but you should use something like `\DeclareOption[nosecnum]{\secnumfalse} \ProcessOptions`  so the user can use `\documentclass[nosecnum]{file}`

Comment: The second to last argument of `\titleformat` needs to contain a dimension, at least `0pt`.

Answer (score 1):

This sort of feature is generally managed through class options. So you could write in your `file.cls` file:

```
\newif\if@unnumberedsections % ❶
\@unnumberedsections

\DeclareOption{unnnumberedsections}
    {\@unnumberedsectionstrue} % ❶

\LoadClass[12pt,a4paper]{report}
\RequirePackage{titlesec}

\if@unnumberedsections % ❶
   \titleformat{\section}{}{\thesection.\ }{}{}
\else
   \titleformat{\section}{}{}{}{}
\fi
```

I've made some small modifications here, using the built-in `\newif` ❶ facility of TeX which is the usual way to manage boolean conditions.¹

The option handling is managed with `\DeclareOption` ❷ which indicates the code to be executed if the option is present. This will be executed by the `\ProcessOptions` command which is *not* present here, at least not explicitly, but since it will be managed when you load the `report` class, by declaring the option before loading the report class, it will get executed when that happens (which means that we need to declare the option before `\LoadClass`.

**But wait, is this how you want to do this?**

Since your change here is to remove section numbers, do you really want to use the mechanism that you're using here? Note that if you have subsections, for example, they will still be numbered 1.1.1, 1.1.2, etc.

LaTeX provides a mechanism for controlling the depth of numbering using the counter `secnumdepth`. What you may actually want to do is define your option as:

```
\DeclareOption{unnumberedsections}
   {\setcounter{secnumdepth}{0}}
```

which will cause everything below chapters to be unnumbered.

---

1. This is one of many idiosyncracies of programming in TeX since there aren't really variables and everything happens through macro expansion.